# Declined flags because of edit approval delay - what to do?

Tags: support, edits, comment-flags

I edited a comment answer into [this question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/10011/drill-core-stratigraphic-data) on Opendata.SE, and marked the corresponding comments as obsolete:

[image]

The edit approval took approx 23 hours because multiple users need to see that. In the meantime a mod declined my flags.

I regularly do this (insert comment/pending edit + mark as obsolete). Does a mod see the relation between these two (in which case this is a one off incident), or is that relation unclear and is there anything **I** can do to avoid this?
Waiting for my edits to be approved and then coming back to mark the comments takes too much effort - in that case I will refrain from marking them.

It's no big deal, I just get the warning *Your previous flags were declined*, and I'm not criticising anyone. I'm curious if this can be 'prevented'.
(And on the sites where my edits no longer need approval I'm sure a mod sees the edit together with the flags).

Comment: The problem is that your edit might be rejected (even though it's a good one). Up to the moment that it is approved, the comments aren't obsolete.

Comment: "Waiting for my edits to be approved and then coming back to mark the comments takes too much effort" - fair enough, so don't do that. The world won't fall if those comments will still be there, and someone else who notice them in the future can also flag.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Does a mod see the relation between these two?

No, a moderator just sees what the current state of the post and its comments is.

And even if they look closer and notice your pending edit, it still doesn't make the comments obsolete. The comments are *essential* for reviewers to determine if the edit was okay.

The edit might also get rejected, making the comments not obsolete after all.

> Waiting for my edits to be approved and then coming back to mark the comments takes too much effort - in that case I will refrain from marking them.

That is indeed the best option. You might come back if your edit gets approved (you will see the +2 reputation gain from it, so you don't have to come back until then). Often marking them as obsolete isn't that important, so you could leave them sitting there.

Comment: Ah, I totally overlooked *The comments are essential for reviewers to determine if the edit was okay.*